# state_machine using after_failure with ActiveRecord transactions

Tags: ruby, activerecord, state-machine

I'm using ruby [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) to manage processing documents. As the document progresses the SM states manage the extra validations needed.

If any step fails, such as the document being the wrong dimensions, I want to record this so I can inform a user who is waiting for the conversion to complete.

My plan was to use SM after_failure to fill in a failed_at timestamp in the model. The polling user interface would see the processing has failed and display an appropriate message.

My issue is that if a transition fails it rolls back the transaction including the after_failure method. This means the user never finds out that the processing failed and unfortunately sits in front of their screen indefinitely.

In the example below I want the :fail_transaction method to run despite the transition failing. I'm open to any ideas or alternate ways to notify the user of failure.

Notes:

- The :use_transaction => false option for state machine doesn't seem
  to make a difference.
- I considered putting the fail conversion into a worker queue to escape the transaction but as I'm using delayed_job so queue entries are also wound back.
- This project is shamefully still on Rails 2.3.x & ruby 1.8.x

Example code:

```
state_machine :state, :initial => :new do

  state :new

  state :original_uploaded do
    validates_presence_of :original_file
  end

  state :original_converted do
    validates_presence_of :pdf
  end

  state :conversion_complete do
    validates :pdf_dimensions_correct
  end

  event :process do
    transition :new => :original_uploaded
    transition :original_uploaded => :original_converted
    transition :original_converted => :conversion_complete
  end

  after_transition :on => :process, :do => :process

  before_transition any => :original_converted, :do => :convert_original_to_pdf
  before_transition any => :conversion_complete, :do => :extract_pdf_metadata

  after_failure :on => :process, :do => :fail_conversion

end

def fail_conversion
  update_attribute(:failed_at, Time.now) # Should update dispite being invalid state
end

def convert_original_to_pdf
  #...
end

def extract_pdf_metadata
  #...
end

def pdf_dimensions_correct
  errors.add(...)
end
```

Thanks in advance!